# Compass multiple css transitions

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-transitions

How can one do multiple css transitions like this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvYvq/3/) with  [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)?

What I am trying to do is basecly write this code below with Compass.

```
-webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-out, background .9s .5s ease-out; 
   -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-out, background .9s .5s ease-out; 
     -o-transition: top 0.3s ease-out, background .9s .5s ease-out; 
        transition: top 0.3s ease-out, background .9s .5s ease-out;
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/#mixin-transition

`@include transition( top 0.3s ease-out, background .9s .5s ease-out );`

Comment: Does this still work for you? I came up with that aswell, but what I get is `transition: top 0.3s ease-out background .9s .5s ease-out;`. It leaves the comma out! Is this a (known) bug? [Am using `compass 0.13.alpha.12`]

Comment: @marczking not sure if https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins/issues/34 is related. it works for me if I pass in lists: `@include transition((top 0.3s ease-out), (background 0.9s ease-out));

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation: 
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/#mixin-transition

It might have changed over the years but it is now like this:

```
single-transition($property, $duration, $function, $delay)
```

Notice the $delay is last, not as in the correct answer where it is before last.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using a mixin to define you transition and you get this error:

> error: mixin transition only takes 1 arguments; given 2

try enclosing your values between parenthesis like:

```
@include transition( (bottom .5s, background 2s) );
```

Comment: The question is specific to Compass, which provides a transition mixin that would not generate this error.